# Why is passport.authenticate called twice?

Tags: passport.js

I'm learning passportjs. I'm looking at the passport-google example here
https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google/blob/master/examples/signon/app.js

It contains the following lines of code

```
app.get('/auth/google',
passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

And subsequently, these lines:

```
app.get('/auth/google/return',
passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

Can someone help me understand why the duplicate call to passport.authenticate is needed?

Answer (score 3):

The two calls actually serve distinct functions depending on what type of request is received and at what stage of authentication the flow is at.

The first call `passport.authenticate` is to initiate the OpenID authentication (which is what `passport-google` uses under the hood) and the second call (for the `return` URL) is used by the OpenID Provider to respond to the prior authentication request.  The Passport Strategy reads the relevant assertion from the second request and processes it accordingly -- eventually leading to either a redirection to `/login` if the assertion failed or a redirection to `/` if the assertion succeeded.

The source code at https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-openid/blob/master/lib/passport-openid/strategy.js#L164 contains some well-written comments explaining what's happening.

As a final aside, other Passport strategies may behave differently, so not every strategy with a callback necessarily requires the same seemingly "repeated" calls to `passport.authenticate(...)`.